# What is the trick with c:\program?

Tags: windows

I found that taking any exe file, renaming it to **program** (without extension) and putting it in C:\ root folder might cause strange things in windows like showing this application when other programs start.
What is it? is it some kind of backdoor?

p.s if you restart windows after doing so - you get a warning about it.

thanks,
Adi Barda

Comment: This probably isn't programming related, but I'd like to know if what Adi's claiming is true or not.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the fact that some programs don't know how to access C:/Program Files/*.* because it has a space. Then they are trying to execute C:/program, which in your case turns out to be the file you created.

Comment: In fact, the documentation about CreateProcess <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx> tells us the order of commands tried when not using quotes to enclose the command.